# Autocomple form finds city but cannot access it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-places-autocomplete

Google place autocomplete address form doesn't return locality even tough it show it in the autocomplete?
Using their original example as well as trying to change locality for postal_town I cannot acces city name.

It is quite perplexed situation where I can see city's name 'Presov' in the autocomplete form but I cannot access it with locality nor postal_town. Any ideas?

[An example in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO6BE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally figured it out. In my case I called https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Matice+Slovenskej,+Presov,+Slovakia&key=YOUR_API_KEY
where you can see the response in JSON key and all the specific fields that are returned. I was not able to find this info in official documentation.